# Glance Screen missing RedStone Win10Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-620, glance, redstone-builds

I am having **Lumia 620** and probably I could not get the **Windows 10 Mobile RedStone** build. So, I did the registry hack using *DHTUpgradeAdvisor* and got the build **10.0.14393.67**

But I could not find the *Glance Screen* settings inside *Personalisation*. I tried installing *Glance Screen* official app, but it crash on start, probably it won't work with this build.

Is there any work around so that I can get back the Glance Screen in this build?

Comment: i tried the same trick, i could download 14393.67 on my 520 but couldnt install it, please help me!

Comment: What error it showing up?

Comment: error:try again, when i click that, its downloading the update again, i did it 3 times already! one of my frnd could do it on his 630, why cant i work it up in my 520!

Comment: Do you found any specific error code or just the above message?

Comment: well, am doing it again, i'll notify you the error if it fails again, (hopefully not!)

Comment: Make sure that you have enough storage space before. Let that won't be the reason anyway

Comment: i hav 3Gb space in internal and i got the error again, Error 0x80091007

Comment: Let me know about your Windows Insider status

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you to post a new question on this, as we are discussing off topic here.

Comment: Glance screen works very well for me L640 W10 official update, so the problem can be in your hack tool

Answer (score 1):

In that hack you simulate that your phone is a Lumia 950, does it have glance screen? I'm not sure, but have you tried this?

In order to enable glance screen in Lumia 650 / 950, follow these steps. 
[image: Glance screen in Extras]

You can see the following options in the glance screen settings.

[image: enable glance screen in Lumia]

1. **Mode**: Here, you can set the time after the phone is locked when the glance screen appears and works. Set it to 30 sec or 15 min, or you can shut it off, or even select to keep always on. Since, glance screen hardly uses any battery of your Lumia 650 /950, keeping it on is a better choice.
2. Under content, you can select Date / Notification icons to show on the glance screen.
3. **Exceptions**: This gives the option of turning off glance screen when you don't want your screen to lighten up specially during your sleep. Under the night mode, select the color of font for the glance screen or keep it off/hide it. Also, you can set start / end time in which the glance enabling glance screen for Lumia 650 /950 won't work so you can sleep without any lights.

   - Source: http://www.windowsphonesearch.com/2016/05/how-to-enable-glance-screen-in-lumia-650-lumia-950.html